# i want to test OSB flow via its proxy service url in browser. With its URI it gives error and using postman also gives error

Tags: proxy, unmarshalling, osb

i installed postman utility in my Google chrome browser and i put proxy URl in postman utility address bar after selecting http post method. URL is `http://localhost:7021/Testing2CBR/Proxy/ProxyGateway`

and request code is

```
   <loanRequest xmlns:java="java:normal.client">
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:Name>maha</java:Name>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:SSN>1234</java:SSN>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:Rate>1</java:Rate>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:Amount>10</java:Amount>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:NumOfYear>3</java:NumOfYear>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:Notes>123</java:Notes>
<loanRequest>
```

but it gives me error

```
 <faultstring>BEA-382030: Failure while unmarshalling message: Failed to parse XML text</faultstring>
```

i modified my request as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>

<loanRequest xmlns:java="java:normal.client">
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:Name>maha</java:Name>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:SSN>1234</java:SSN>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:Rate>1</java:Rate>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:Amount>10</java:Amount>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:NumOfYear>3</java:NumOfYear>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <java:Notes>123</java:Notes>
<loanRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and i also tried adding header over the request message, as mentioned in OSB proxy console window

```
 <soap:Header xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
</soap:Header>
```

but i am still getting the error. How should i format my xml request message so that Proxy service url accepts it in my postman utility of google chrome browser with http post method?

Comment: Are you able to execute proxy service via sb-console ? What exactly this proxy service does ?

Comment: Yes i am able to test my proxy using OSB test console. It uses 2 ways of request input (tabs)...1 is Form and 2nd is XML. while inserting values in Form user doesnt takes care of format because user just puts values in request tags...while writing xml again throws same error of "unable to parse xml"

Answer (score 1):

Test the proxy using the debug option in `/sbconsole` . You can enter the request, or you can choose enter the entire soap envelope. The pre-filled values in the text area can be used to create your own message.

Comment: By sbconsole if you mean OSB test console, then i can just see 4 options: execute, execute-save, reset, close. Any other way of getting debug option plz!

Comment: 1. You need to start your server in debug mode either from eclipse or jdev.
2. You need to put break points in the flow to exactly pinpoint which activity is throwing the exception.
3.

Comment: If were able to run your proxy successfully from sb-console using 1st tab(Form). In second tab (XML) you need to give soapenv:Envelope in the request.

Comment: One more thing - The xml you have pasted in the question is not well formed - <loanRequest> doesn't end. Is that the issue ?